# Cannot GET/"url" error when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

Im currently working on react app with vite and express.There is no problem when i go to url from home page but when i refresh it on the url i get the Cannot GET/users error.

I find this code block for solution

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/your/index.html'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
})
```

but when i pass my index.html file `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.` this error appears on console please help.

These are the server routes

```
app.use(`/api/user`, userRouter);
app.use(`/api/category`, categoryRouter);
```

These are user routes

```
router.get(`/:id`, authenticate, authorizedAdmin, getUserById);
router.route("/profile").get(authenticate, getCurrentUser);
router.post(`/`, createUser);
router.post("/login", loginUser);
router.post("/logout", logoutUser);
router.put("/profile", authenticate, updateCurrentUserProfile);
router.put("/:id", authenticate, authorizedAdmin, updateUserProfileById);
router.delete("/profile", authenticate, deleteCurrentUserPofile);
router.delete("/:id", authenticate, authorizedAdmin, deleteUserProfileById);
router.get(`/`, authenticate, authorizedAdmin, getAllUsers);
```

As I said, if I go to the page that receives all users from the home page, there is no problem. But if I reload while I'm already on that page browser gives Cannot GET/ error please help [This is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6OsH.png)

Comment: See if https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#other-solutions helps with the Express setup.